# Why wallet download page is unecrypted?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Why is monero website using https but when you click to download the command line wallet you get a warning from the browser that the site is not safe?  You end up having to click through warnings to get to the downloads?

Also, how do I verify that my download is the correct one and hasn't been messed with?

Thanks,

Glenn

Comment: Seems to be https here, along with the download link.  Sure you have the right website?  https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/?  To check, verify the hashes. THe one from the site and one of the actually download.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/ uses HTTPS. The links on that page going to the actual downloads appear to be HTTPS as well. If there is one or several which is/are not, post the actual links as well as where they appear.

The site uses HSTS:

> Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload

So your browser should not access it via HTTP if it's already accessed it and spotted the HSTS header.

You might be using the wrong website, such as monero.org, a well known squatter.